# Double dual of torsion-free sheaves are locally free?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, modules, sheaf-theory

I was reading Nakajima's "Lectures on Hilbert schemes of points on
surfaces". In Chapter 2 he says that if $E$ is a torsion-free sheaf then $E^{**}$ is locally free. I guess that by `torsion-free' sheaf he meant on every open sets $U \subset X = \mathbb{P}^2$, $E(U)$ is a torsion-free $\mathscr{O}_X(U)$-module. I also think that duality is defined by $E^*= \text{Hom}_{\mathscr{O}_X}(E,\mathscr{O}_X)$. But then how do I show that $E^{**}$ is locally free?

**Additional confusion on the matter:**
I'm not sure if I'm allowed to assume that $E$ is quasi-coherent or coherent here. He mentioned at the start of the chapter that $\text{rank} E = r$, which suggest that $E$ has to be coherent, but by talking about the rank of $E$ don't we already assume $E$ is locally free? How can we define a rank on a module that is not free?

Comment: Usually the rank of a not necessarily free module is defined as the rank of $M \otimes K(R)$, where $K(R)$ is the fraction field of the ring.

Comment: Rank $1$ reflexive sheaves on a regular scheme are invertible sheaves. This should be in Hartshorne's article _Stable reflexive sheaves_. I don't think this has any hope of being true for higher ranks.

Comment: In that book $X$ is a surface, where it is true that $E$ torsionfree $=>$ $E^{**}$ is locally free. This follows from that fact that $E^{**}$ is reflexive, hence not locally free on a closed subset of codimension $>=$ 3 on $X$, hence nowhere.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Regarding the question about what type of sheaves are under consideration, the answer is *coherent sheaves*.  The corresponding algebra concepts are from the theory of finitely generated modules over Noetherian rings (and especially, from the theory of *depth* and related concepts).

As noted in comments, the property of reflexivity implying local freeness is special to surfaces.    On a variety, a reflexive sheaf will be $S_2$ (where $S_n$ are the depth conditions that appear in the definition of Cohen--Macaulay: on a $n$-dimensional variety, being Cohen--Macaulay is the same as being $S_n$).

A [theorem of Auslander--Buchsbaum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auslander%E2%80%93Buchsbaum_formula) shows that on a smooth variety, a coherent sheaf that is Cohen--Macaulay is locally free.  So for smooth surfaces, reflexive equals $S_2$ equals Cohen--Macaulay equals locally free.

If $X$ is a smooth three-fold, if $\mathcal I$ is the ideal sheaf of a point, and if $\mathcal K$ denotes the kernel of a surjection $\mathcal F \to \mathcal I$, with $\mathcal F$ locally free, then $\mathcal K$ is reflexive, i.e. $S_2$, but not locally free.

Incidentally, torsion-free is the same as $S_1$, and can be thought of geometrically as saying that the sheaf admits no non-zero sections whose support is a proper closed subvariety.  (More generally, if you are on a variety or scheme that is allowed to be reducible, then the condition is that the support of a non-zero section should be a union of irreducible components.)

Regarding the use of *rank* in the non-locally free context:
the generic fibre of a torsion-free coherent sheaf is a finite rank vector space over the function field of $X$, and this is how its rank is defined.

Finally: I've found [these notes](https://www.math.utah.edu/~schwede/Notes/GeneralizedDivisors.pdf) of Karl Schwede helpful in the past when trying to think about this material.